# pip3 not installing in correct folder

Tags: python

While python3 expects modules to be in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4`, pip3 installs them in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`. This results in python3 not finding packages that pip3 says are installed.

I tried cutting and pasting the stuff in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages` to `/usr/local/lib/python3.4`, but I end up with weird errors, like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/Cython/Build/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .Dependencies import cythonize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 51, in <module>
    from ..Compiler.Main import Context, CompilationOptions, default_options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .Symtab import ModuleScope
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/Cython/Compiler/Symtab.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import PyrexTypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/Cython/Compiler/PyrexTypes.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .Code import UtilityCode, LazyUtilityCode, TempitaUtilityCode
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/Cython/Compiler/Code.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

What do I do now? I'm on Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-bit.

[EDIT]

This problem was a complete mess and I still have no clue what happened before. I have given up trying to get Python to work, as I have found an application that does the same thing as the Python application I was trying to get working. It's such a pain.

Comment: I would recommend you to install pip packages with the --user flag, so they are installed to your home folder instead of system folders. This minimizes the chances that you screw up something.

Comment: Or just add the installed folder to your path

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Well, I've already messed up. I've tried purging the Python installation and reinstalling it, but the issue still persists. How do I start over, so to speak?

Comment: @OferSadan (previous comment)

Comment: You can also install to a specific directory by using `pip install ____ -t my/custom/path`

Comment: @Connor Doing that results in symbols not being defined.